# I want to make a daily home workout schedule

Tags: muscle, workout, chest, routine

M/18/5'5"/105lbs (1.6m/48kg).

I am an amateur  when it comes to working out but I would like to build muscle.

I want to make a daily home workout schedule where each day I work on different body parts than they day before. I was thinking:

- Monday: Biceps
- Tuesday: Abs
- Wednesday: Chest
- Thursday: Biceps
- Friday: Abs
- Saturday: Chest
- Sunday: Legs

What do you guys think? Do you have another suggestion?

Comment: Why train diferent muscles in different  days? What sense does it make?

Comment: A mirror-muscles focussed program (even with a token leg day) is a terrible idea, especially when you are dangerously underweight, having a BMI of 18.75. Instead, gaining muscle mass through compound exercises and significantly increased food intake will do you a lot of good. What are your actual goals/reasons for wanting to work out, and what equipment do you have access to?

Comment: I recommend using a premade plan for beginners. You will find plenty online. I also like to make my own stuff, but sometimes the results are such as your plan there. If you want to make your own, just use a decent plan as a guideline and vary with a bit of common sense. Many people in fitness are the other extreme, they like being told what to do and not think for themselves. Sometimes that's what gives you the best results, especially for someone who is new to this.

Comment: Strong lifts 5x5, or starting strength.

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend you add in back workouts as well. Having an overdeveloped chest but a weak back can lead to muscular imbalances and or injuries in the future. Throw in pull ups, supermans (lower back) and reverse hypers. Looking at your workout plan this seems to be an aesthetic endeavor so a back workout would also help develop that V-taper. You can just add biceps to the end of your back day. Also integrate some tricep exercises on your chest day if you're looking to develop big arms because the triceps make up more of the arm than the bicep.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I'd suggest you add back, shoulders and triceps to your workout plan.

Secondly, I'd recommend training more than one muscle group a day for efficiency. A lot of people would suggest chest and tricpes, back and biceps, I'd also say you could do abs after doing legs. Or doing abs on 2 or 3 diffirent days after your workout, so for example after doing legs and after doing shoulders.

You can also try to create a push-pull split but this might be harder to do at home, depending on the type of equipement you have.

Comment: Not that i disagree, I love training those 3, but could you perhaps explain why? back is explained by mobcity. Many beginner plans don't include special exercises for the shoulder or (and especially) triceps.

Comment: Because you'd want to balance your training. You don't want your biceps to eventually overpower your triceps or vice versa. You'll eventually start running into issues and possibly injuries. The same goes for if you train your chest without training your back or your shoulders, eventually something is going to give in.

Comment: I know, but the OP might not. Best include such things via edit. However I'd still argue that you don't really need it at the very beginning.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I'll keep that in mind! I'm not saying he needs to include it, I'm suggesting OP does so because OP wants to build muscle. If you want to build muscle, why would you only train half your body?